# Add URL link in CSS & Html to button

Tags: html, css, url

How do I change a CSS button into a button with URL link?
Ive read I need to also add HTML codes?

The only code for the button I can find is this one:

```
 .ui-state-highlight, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-highlight, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-highlight {
position: relative;
margin-bottom: 1px;
color: #FFF;
background-color: #2265B9;
background-repeat: repeat-x;
background-image: -khtml-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#FCEEC1), to(#EEDC94));
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FCEEC1, #EEDC94);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #FCEEC1, #EEDC94);
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #FCEEC1), color-stop(100%, #EEDC94));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #069CFF, #0A6AB6);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #FCEEC1, #EEDC94);
background-image: linear-gradient(top, #FCEEC1, #EEDC94);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#fceec1', endColorstr='#eedc94', GradientType=0);
border-color: #EEDC94 #EEDC94 #E4C652;
border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
border-width: 1px;
border-style: solid;
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
border-radius: 4px;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
}
```

Im not sure if this is a correct question or correct codes.

Answer (score 2):

Links aren't added through CSS, they're added through the HTML:

```
<a href="http://example.com">My Link</a>
```

If you want it to appear with the styling you've given, simply give it a `.ui-state-highlight` class:

```
<a href="http://example.com" class="ui-state-highlight">My Styled Link</a>
```

Comment: Hi thanks james, but Im confused I dont know exactly where to add this html code, there is only one html file on the CSS button folder,

Comment: How are you adding this button to your page?

Comment: This button comes with the jomres software, and I can only see a CSS jquery file/code from it, not exactly know what you mean though.

Comment: Well normally with HTML and CSS you'd have a HTML page which links to your CSS page for styling. The HTML is where you add elements like links, and the CSS is where you style them.

Comment: Oohh I see, In the folder css/ui_template/mybutton.css there is only a index.html file with only a body and color code, but I guess the oficial html file its not in CSS folders, it must be in another place, well Ill ask to the software dev where is this file location.. thanks James

Answer (score 1):

if you just want to add a link to a button then you can use

```
<button onlick="#"><a href="http://google.com/"> Open this website</a></button>
```

or do you want to open the url into new page??